# Download file using angular js by calling spring rest api

Tags: angularjs, download

I have a Spring Controller which send file in response

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadData(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    File dataJSONFile = dataDownloadService.createAndWriteFile();
    response.setContentType("application/text");
    response.setContentLength(new Long(dataJSONFile.length()).intValue());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="data.json");
    FileCopyUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(dataJSONFile),     
    response.getOutputStream());
}
```

If I write in browser url, `//localhost:8080/myproject/rest/downloadData` It downloads the file.

Now, want to download the file when click on button in using angular js.

I have written following code in angular js to download file

```
angular
    .module('myApp.services')
    .factory(
            'DataDownloadService',
            function($resource) {
                "use strict";
                return {
                    "query" : function() {
                        var ret, restResource;
                        restResource = $resource(
                                '/sand-pp/api/rest/downloadData',
                                {}, {
                                    "query" : {
                                        "method" : "GET",
                                        "isArray" : true,
                                        headers:
                                        {
                                            'Content-Type': 'application/text',
                                            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=data.json'

                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        ret = restResource.query();
                        return ret;
                    }
                };
            });
```

When I call above service nothing is happening but if I print data in callback function is printing data in console.
How to download file in angular js by calling Spring REST api?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a service for the rest call. Try this following:

**window.location.href = DataDownloadService.query();**

It should prompt the browser to download the file (because of Content-Disposition header).